# 'Row is not a member of system.windows.forms.datagrid'

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I was working on datagrid view,for converting datagridview result to excel i have this code :

```
For i = 0 To DG.RowCount - 2
            For j = 0 To DG.ColumnCount - 1
                For k As Integer = 1 To DG.Columns.Count
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k) = DG.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = DG(j, i).Value.ToString()
                Next
            Next
        Next
```

but if some another form i have ,instead of datagrid view i have datagrid,but showing error like this :

**'Row is not a member of system.windows.forms.datagrid'**

Comment: `DataGrid` is not Winform's control. Your code seems ok for `DataGridView`. What another control you are using?

Comment: @Fabio The [DataGrid control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) is a WinForm control. An obsolete one but still...

Comment: So, you have an error in another control code and you show us your working code? Perhaps showing the code that fails will serve you better.

Answer (score -1):

```
 For IntJ = 0 To intGridRowCount - 1
                d = "@" & dgDetails.Item(IntJ, 1).ToString

            Next
```

Try this.

Comment: code  only answer is bad practice say some thing about your code  how this address OP's problem.